# Low memory when creating big size matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, out-of-memory

This code selects randomly J=R*T samples from input image x. x is MxN image.PHi_2 operator first selects randomly R rows out of M and then selects randomly T columns out of N and keeps samples of common  M & N pixels and set others zero.
This code works well for small size images but for big size images (512x512) matlab gives me low memory error(line four when creating Phi2=zeros(J,S1*S2);).Can you please help me to fix it? and also I select R=T=362;

```
function [ y2,Phi2 ] = Phi2_operator( x,R,T )
J=R*T;
[S1,S2]=size(x);
z=zeros(size(x));
y2=zeros(size(x));
Phi2=zeros(J,S1*S2);
k = randperm(S1);
a=k(1:R);
b=sort(a);
l=length(b);
for i=1:l
z(b(i),:)=x(b(i),:);
end
clear i
K=randperm(S2);
A=K(1:T);
B=sort(A);
L=length(B);
for i=1:L
y2(:,B(i))=z(:,B(i));
end
X=find(y2);
for i=1:J
Phi2(i,X(i))=1;
end
end
```

Comment: Yeah. Go to a shop and buy a new computer!

Comment: For a `512 x 512` image, `zeros(J,S1*S2);` gives you `262,144` columns. Depending on what the value of `J` is, this could be a significant amount of RAM. Are you sure you want `S1*S2`?

Comment: How much memory have you got? It shouldn't be that memory intensive

Comment: @excaza J is 131044. yeah I need that big size matrix

Comment: @GameOfThrows  4GB RAM, core i7 cpu, 512HDD.

Comment: @HaybertMarkarian are you really sure? If `J` is `131,044` then `zeros(J,S1*S2)` needs to generate a 274 gigabyte array for a `512 x 512` image. Getting that much RAM might be a bit of a hassle. I would suggest reevaluating your algorithm.

Comment: I agree with excaza Your alternative is to regenerate a zero matrix of S1 * S2 after each iteration, since your Phi2(i,X(i)) = 1 is only called once each iteration, you can then store each of the J slices on the HDD which should prevent the memory problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can optimize your code a bit:

**1.** You can call [`randperm`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) with two arguments: `randperm(n,k)`, which randomly choses `k` samples from the interval `1:n`. That way you don't need to create the variable `a`.

**2.** Instead of assigning the values to `z` and `y2` in a for loop, you can use a vectorized approach: `z(k,:) = x(k,:);`. This is faster and shorter than for loops. You also don't need to sort `k`.

Now to the more important stuff:

**3.** You create `z` and `y2` which both have the full size of `x`, but you only return `y2`. Drop the `z`, that saves you some memory. Again with the help of logical indexing, we get:

```
k1 = randperm(S1,R);
k2 = randperm(S2,T);

y2(k1,k2) = x(k1,k2);
```

**4.** Let's look what `Phi2` is: With `X=find(y2)` you'll get the [*linear* index](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) of every non-zero element in `y2`. A simple example of `Phi2` would look like this:

```
0    0    1    0    0    0    ...
0    0    0    0    1    0    ...
0    0    0    0    0    1    ...
...
```

This tells us that the first non-zero element (first row of `Phi2`) is at the 3rd linear index of `y2`. The second non-zero element (second row) is at the 5th linear index of `y2`. The third non-zero element (third row) is at the 6th linear index of `y2`, and so on. This adds *no* additional knowledge, but needs a huge matrix. I do not think that you really need this, there will probably be ways to solve your problem without creating this matrix.

If you *really* need this huge `Phi2`, you will want to make it a [sparse](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) matrix:

```
Phi2 = sparse(1:J,X,ones(1,J));
```

For a `256*256` image with `R=128` and `T=64`, the full-size matrix would be `4294967296 bytes` which is `4 GB` ! The sparse matrix is only `651272 bytes` or `636 kB`.

Everything put together is

```
function [ y2,Phi2 ] = Phi2_operator( x,R,T )
    J = R * T;
    [S1,S2] = size(x);

    y2 = zeros(size(x));

    k1 = randperm(S1,R);
    k2 = randperm(S2,T);

    y2(k1,k2) = x(k1,k2);  

    X=find(y2);
    Phi2 = sparse(1:J,X,ones(1,J));
end
```

Comment: thanks but I get error on k1 = randperm(S1,R);    ??? Error using ==> randperm
Too many input arguments.

Comment: I think it is because of my matlab version my matlab is ver. 2011

Comment: Oh yes, that came with MATLAB R2011b, so bad luck. Guess you'll just have to change that back to `k1 = randperm(S1); k1 = k1(1:R);` and `k2` similarly.